# How to get a "bulge" more square in nature?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, distort

How can I make some text look like this?

[image: http://gyazo.com/505d4df75315cea5410e77d19f40eadf]

I tried using the bulge but I couldn't get it to look square enough.

Comment: By the way I mean in Photoshop CC

Comment: Most things like this aren't done with Photoshop. They are done in a vector application such as Illustrator. That isn't to say they *can't* be done with Photoshop. They can, but it generally takes much more care than just using some built in distort options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perspective warp is your friend!

[image: edit > perspective warp]

*edit > perspective warp*